# Variable de tipo ambiguo ¨a0¨ derivada del uso de "*"

Tags: haskell, lambda

Tengo la siguiente función

```
evaluar = (\a-> a) (\b c-> b + c ) (\d f-> d * f)
```

pero cuando la ejecuto me da el siguiente error y no puedo descifrar que es

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `*'
prevents the constraint `(Num a0)' from being solved.
Relevant bindings include
```

Comment: Por aclarar la pregunta, ¿sabes qué _signatura_ debería tener la función `evaluar`?

Answer (score 0):

Las operaciones `(+)` y `(*)` están definidas para argumentos del mismo tipo y de la clase `Num`. Así tendríamos las siguientes signaturas:

```hs
(\a -> a) :: a2 -> a2
(\b c -> b + c ) :: Num a1 => a1 -> a1 -> a1
(\d f -> d * f) :: Num a0 => a0 -> a0 -> a0
```

La expresión lambda `(\a -> a)` es en realidad la *identidad*, por lo que hace nada cuando se aplica.

Si vamos aplicando las funciones:

```hs
(\a -> a) (\b c -> b + c ) (\d f -> d * f) -->
(\b c -> b + c ) (\d f -> d * f) -->
(\b -> \c -> b + c ) (\d -> \f -> d * f) -->
\c -> (\d -> \f -> d * f) + c
```

Esta última suma no tiene sentido. El compilador está buscando un tipo `Num (a0 -> a0 -> a0), Num a0` que no puede resolver.